# c# \ Generic \ use generic on variable within a function body

Tags: c#, variables, generics

Is it possible to use Generic mechanism within function body?

for exammple

```
if (!(someClass is IClass<T, G> where T : someInterface, G : anotherInterface))
{
    return;
 }
```

or do casting like this:

```
var v = (IClass <T, G> where T : someInterface, G: anotherInterface)something;
```

Comment: The code is nonsensical. You cannot have instances of open types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but you have to make sure your interface is *covariant*:

```
interface IClass<out T, out S>
{
    // Methods that can return a T or S but not accept one as input
}
```

By marking the type parameters as `out`, you are basically saying "I will only ever get a `T` or an `S` *out* of this interface". For example, `IEnumerable<out T>` as you can only get a `T` out of it, but only `List<T>` because you can put a `T` into a list as well as get one out.

Having defined your interface as such, an `IClass<string, string>` *is* an `IClass<object, object>`: you know your `IClass<string, string>` will only ever give you a `string`, but since a `string` is an `object` then that's fine, and if you assign it to an `IClass<object, object>` you know it will only ever give you an `object`.

(You *can't* do this if you interface allows you to put a `T` or an `S` *into* something. If this was the case, and you assigned your `IClass<string, string>` to an `IClass<object, object>`, you could try to put an `int` into it and it would fail, because the underlying class only really accepts a `string`.)

What this then lets you do is

```
if (!(something is IClass<object, object>))
{
    return;
}
```

or

```
var v = (IClass<object, object>)something;
```

and both will work if `something` is *actually* an object that implements, say, `IClass<string, string>`.

Comment: This answer really helped me understand that `out` keyword, which Ive always struggled with. +1

Answer (score 1):

For the first example, yes - you just need to specify the types:

```
if (!(someClass is IClass<ISomeInterface, IAnotherInterface>))
{
    return;
 }
```

The other is muct the same:

```
var v = (IClass <ISomeInterface, IAnotherInterface>)something;
```

Although its probably better to use `as`

```
var v = something as IClass <ISomeInterface, IAnotherInterface>;
if(v != null)
{
    // Do something.
}
```

The second line above is important - by using `as` in place of a direct cast you wont get an `InvalidCastException` if it fails, but `v` will be null if the cast using `as` fails. This technique gives you a little more control over failure if your attempt to cast is invalid. (Consider *why* the conversion would be invalid: if that represents a situation where you know longer know what the world looks like, the `InvalidCastException` is probably the correct approach. If it's reasonable for the object *not* to be an instance of the interface, then `as` is your friend.)

Comment: It's not *generally* better to use `as` than a cast. It depends on whether a conversion failure represents an *error* which should logically cause an exception or not.

Comment: @JonSkeet needs an "or worse" ;p

Comment: Not entirely true. `int[]` would fullfill `where T : IEnumerable` but `new List<IEnumerable>() is List<int[]>` would be false

Comment: Thanks - regarding --> if (!(someClass is IClass<ISomeInterface, IAnotherInterface>)) - can I change ISomeInterface to class and not interdace - and the derived class will work? I have a feeling it won't work.

Comment: For a general interface `IClass`, `someClass is IClass<ISomeInterface, IAnotherInterface>` _won't_ give `true` if `someClass` is actually an `IClass<SomeInterfaceImpl, AnotherInterfaceImpl>`.

Comment: Wow, a really flippant addition to this answer got a comment from @JonSkeet \*swoons\*. (I did say "probably better" rather than "generally better" though! Thats probably as in "wont throw a cryptic exception if/when it goes wrong")

Comment: @Jamiec: Well, it *will* throw a cryptic exception (NullReferenceException) if you use `as` and then use the result unconditionally. It will throw an entirely *non-cryptic* exception (InvalidCastException) if you cast.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Yes of course. And IOE is sometimes *more* cryptic as you said. Anyway, that last bit was meant to be a throwaway, its clearly not so ive expanded the explanation a little to be clear. If you can word it better and you feel so inclined feel free to modify.

Comment: @Jamiec: Have added a parenthetical explanation of when you might prefer which. Hope that's okay; feel free to remove entirely :)

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
if (!(someClass is IClass<someInterface, anotherInterface>)
{
    return;
}
```

or via reflection:

```
var t = someClass.GetType()
Type[] typeParameters = t.GetGenericArguments();
if (!typeParameters[0].IsSubclassOf(typeof(someInterface)) || 
    !typeParameters[1].IsSubclassOf(typeof(anotherInterface)))
{
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`where` constraints are to be applied to the generic method itself. You can use the desired types with no problem.

On a side note: don't check for *false*, it's more confusing on the long run.

```
if (someClass is IClass<someInterface, anotherInterface>)
{
    // your code
}
// else { return; } // no longer needed!
```

Expanding and enveloping the code in a generic method, it would look like this:

```
void myMethod<T, U>()
    where T : someInterface
    where U : anotherInterface
{
    if (someClass is IClass<T, U>)
    {
        // your code
    }
    // else { return; } // no longer needed!
}
```